# Install MySQL in Ubuntu for XAMPP in 14.04

Tags: software-installation, mysql, xampp

I was having problem since some time using XAMPP. In terminal the MySQL starts as normal but when it comes to app, it saying MySQL stopped working. So I removed MySQL and hope installing it again will fix the issue. please share the command for install MySQL in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Followed this guide and reinstalled MySQL. Still MySQL starts in the terminal and stop on XAMPP UI. Even restarting does not work. The used to install MysQL is : http://archanaschangale.wordpress.com/2013/08/23/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu/

Comment: To be sure, I restarted the PC and went on with XAMPP > phpmyadmin only to get this error message " 
Error
MySQL said: Documentation

#2002 - No such file or directory
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured). 
 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed."

Comment: Just to make sure: The server is up, right? `sudo service mysql start`.

Comment: It was working fine before. Suddenly this issue popped up

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install phpadmin
```

Then access your phpmyadmin service with this web link (firefox):

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
```